# C++11 subobject alignment

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

C+11 [basic.align] says:

> An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type; stricter alignment can be requested using the alignment speciﬁer

Then shortly after gives an example:

```
struct B { long double d; };
struct D : virtual B { char c; }
```

And says the following of the example:

> When D is the type of a complete object, it will have a subobject of type B, so it must be aligned appropriately for a long double. If D appears as a subobject of another object that also has B as a virtual base class, the B subobject might be part of a diﬀerent subobject, reducing the alignment requirements on the D subobject.

So what of the alignment requirement imposed upon all objects with object type D? I understand the D subobject to have object type D, which would make it subject to this same requirement. How can the appearance of D as a subobject remove these requirements when they apply to all subobjects? Or should I understand this to mean that complete D objects have further requirements to those imposed by the object type and that these requirements may be weakened when D appears as a subobject?

Answer (score 0):

It's because `D` is derived from `B` using *virtual inheritance*. This means if you define yet another object type, derived from `D` as well as `B` (again virtually),

```
struct E : D , virtual B
{ /*...*/ };
```

then the `B` subobject will be present in `E` objects *only once*, not twice. Hence the `D` subobject of an `E` object may not contain the `B` subobject and therefore enjoy relaxed alignment requirements. (The `E` object as a whole would still be subject to the full alignment requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

The hypothetical class inheriting that "another object" that has `D` as a base, will still have that strictest alignment requirement. It's *just* the `D` subobject that may be relaxed, as the `B` context gets taken away from it. It's just quibbling: no loosening on the final object.

Comment: Are you saying that the requirement from the object type only applies to complete objects? If so, why doesn't it say "complete objects"? I take "every object of that type" to include subobjects.

Comment: @user3152450: Subobjects are not of "that type"